# Exception while trying to convert from spring mvc to spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception

I tried to convert from spring mvc to spring boot but exception in abstractclass methods

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.supportsSourceType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.supportsSourceType(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:79)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.supportsEvent(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:282)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:343)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1227)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1216)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:9)

Comment: What do you mean you're trying to convert? Spring Boot and Spring MVC can work together just fine. Can we see some code?

Comment: trying to convert spring mvc to spring boot